# Buying new smartphone

Tags: smartphones

I'm buying a new smartphone, and I wanna make a smart decission about it. I want the best for the price, but I don't wanna read a bunch of reivews.

I'm buying at a price range of Samsung J3, but it can be any other model.

I don't know should I go for some top brands like Samsung, or try with something like GM or Alcatel. I mean, why are GM and Alcatel so cheap, are they really low quality, or? I don't believe it's low quality, GM is Google right, does that mean it's gotta be good since it's from Google?

Samsung offers much less for the price than GM, Alcatel and Cubot, why is that so, is Samsung overrated?

Can I buy from GM or Alcatel without fear that it will break soon?

I haven't found a single review GM 4G and Lenovo K10a40.

[This](https://www.sancta-domenica.hr/komunikacije/gsm.aspx#page=2) is the store where I'll be buying, it's Croatian, but you'll understand, I'm looking at about 1000 kn price range. 1 USD is about 7kn.

Comment: I _think_ you got the currency conversion wrong, surely you are not ready to spend 7k USD on a phone? ;)

Comment: What requirements do you have for this phone? You make it clear that you are worried about quality, and we do have your budget, but we don't have anything else. Would you like an SD Card slot, dual sim cards, small form factor or a phablet? What apps will you use? If you can [edit] your question with these answers, we can reopen your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the only phone on that website I would personally recommend is probably your first suggestion, the Samsung J3.

Samsung devices have good build quality and performance overall, they also last a long time, from personal experience.

Otherwise, I would most likely recommend the LG smartphones, either of the two below:

- [LG X210 K7](https://www.sancta-domenica.hr/mobitel-lg-x210-k7.aspx)
- [LG K350 K8](https://www.sancta-domenica.hr/mobitel-lg-k350-k8-dual-sim-crni-1.aspx)

To be reasonable, the General Mobile (GM) phones dont look too bad on paper, its just that i have never heard of them.

My personal advice would be to buy a Motorola G5 and get it shipped to your country if you are looking for a pure and fast android experience.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I need to buy at that store because I have discount there.